# Co-ordinate Points on a 3D Plot

Tags: graphics3d

I have a 3D graph:

[image]

I want to figure out the values of the variable in the horizontal axes for which the graph has the highest value -- seeing the vertical axis, the value of variables where plot has the value ~ 0.1.

How would I go about doing that?

**Edit:**

The code is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

G = 0.01;
β = 1;
ωc = 50;
J = 1;
ϕ = 0;
θ = π/2;
η = Exp[I ϕ]*Tan[θ/2];
Clear[ψ];
ψ[α_, χ_] = Exp[I α] * Tan[χ/2];

integralgamma[ω_, τ_] := 
 4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - 
  Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2];

integraldelta[ω_, τ_] := 
 4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sin[ω τ] - 
  ω τ)/ω^2;

old[τ_] := (Abs[η]/(1 + Abs[η]^2) )^(4 J) * 
 Sum[Binomial[2 J, J + m] * Binomial[2 J, J + p] * 
  Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) * 
   Exp[-NIntegrate[
    integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
     Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 3]* (m - p)^2] * 
       Exp[- I * 
        NIntegrate[
         integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
          Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15, 
           PrecisionGoal -> 3]* (m^2 - p^2)]  , {m, -1, 1, 1}, {p, -1, 
            1, 1}];

new[α_, χ_, τ_] := (Abs[ψ[α, χ]]/(1 
 + Abs[ψ[α, χ]]^2) )^(2 J)*(Abs[η]/(1 + 
  Abs[η]^2) )^(2 J) * 
   Sum[Binomial[2 J, J + m] * 
    Binomial[2 J, 
     J + p] * (Conjugate[ψ[α, χ]]*η)^(m) * 
      (Conjugate[η]*ψ[α, χ])^(p) *
       Exp[-NIntegrate[
        integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
         Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15, 
          PrecisionGoal -> 3]* (m - p)^2] * 
           Exp[- I * 
            NIntegrate[
             integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
              Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15, 
               PrecisionGoal -> 3]* (m^2 - p^2)]  , {m, -1, 1, 1}, {p, -1, 
                1, 1}];

Plot3D[new[α, χ, 0.9] - old[0.9], {α, 0, 
 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

Comment: Mind posting a code to generate that `Graphic`? If you have the function, you could use `FindMaximum`.

Comment: @JHM Done. See the edited post.

Comment: Try `FindMaximum[{new[α, χ, 0.9] - old[0.9], 0 < α < 2π && 0 < χ < π}, {α, χ}]`

Comment: you might want to apply `Chop` to your functions since they return complex results with essentially zero imaginary part.

Comment: @george2079 isn't the result real? How is it complex? Also how do I use the chop command -- and what is it's advantage over the output I already have?

Comment: I copied your code into a fresh notebook and then ran `table = Table[{\[Alpha], \[Chi], new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], 0.9], 
   old[0.9], new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], 0.9] - old[0.9]}, {\[Alpha], 0, 
   2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/10}, {\[Chi], 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/10}]`. Try that and you will see the problem with imaginary components. Apply `Chop` to say `new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], 0.9] - old[0.9]` and the small imaginary component goes away.

Comment: Alternatively, try using `Re` command. (e.g. `Re[1 + 3 I]`).

Comment: @JHM and others: When I run `FindMaximum[
 Re[new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], 0.9`]] - Re[old[0.9`]], {\[Alpha], 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {\[Chi], 0, \[Pi]}]`, I get the error `Infinity::indet: "Indeterminate expression (0. +0.\ I)\ ComplexInfinity encountered. "`

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the answer for the maximum value by simply inspecting the graph -- for example, we can do this for a 2D graph by using the drawing tools.

Comment: @JackLaVigne and others: Even when I use the `Chop` command in the previous syntax, I get the same error.

Comment: Code: `FindMaximum[
 Chop[new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], 0.9`] - old[0.9`]], {\[Alpha], 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {\[Chi], 0, \[Pi]}]`

Comment: That is because of the definition of your functions. Try the exercise I gave you and examine the output.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* extract the data from the plot and look for the maximum z value:

```
p = Plot3D[new[α, χ, 0.9] - old[0.9], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π},
  MaxRecursion -> 0, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 20]

Cases[p, GraphicsComplex[pts_, __] :> MaximalBy[pts, Last], -1]
(* {{{2.31486, 2.14951, 0.145981}}} *)
```

However be aware that the result depends upon the sampling of `Plot`, it is unlikely that you happen to have a sample point precisely at the function's maximum. Instead you could use `FindMaximum` which will seek a local maximum:

```
FindMaximum[new[α, χ, 0.9] - old[0.9], {α, 1, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 1, 0, π}]
(* {0.146192, {α -> 2.34597, χ -> 2.11486}} *)
```

or `NMaximize` which will seek a global maximum:

```
NMaximize[{Re[new[α, χ, 0.9] - old[0.9]], 0 <= α <= 2 π, 0 <= χ <= π}, {α, χ}]
(* {0.146192, {α -> 3.93721, χ -> 1.02673}} *)
```

Note that both maximization functions get a higher maximum than was found from the plot data. Also the function has two maxima in the region, and FindMaximum and NMaximize have found different ones.

Here are the locations marked on a contour plot:

```
ContourPlot[new[α, χ, 0.9] - old[0.9], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π},
 Epilog -> Point[{
    {2.314857831775101`, 2.149510702065181`},
    {2.3459738958969076`, 2.114862568462617`},
    {3.937211440432837`, 1.0267300479686081`}}]]
```

[image]

Note: `NMaximize` and other numerical optimization functions can run into trouble when they attempt to evaluate the objective function symbolically. The commonly used solution is to define the objective function with a `NumericQ` pattern test so that it returns unevaluated for symbolic arguments. For example

```
f[α_?NumericQ, χ_?NumericQ, τ_] := Re[new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ]]

Table[NMaximize[{f[α, χ, τ], 0 <= α <= 2 π, 0 <= χ <= π}, {α, χ}], {τ, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]
(* {{0., {α -> 0., χ -> 1.5708}}, 
 {1.11022*10^-16, {α -> 0., χ -> 1.5708}}, etc...  *)
```

Comment: So, given that the 3D plot may have a different number of maxima -- what is the best way to go about finding the values of the variables that maximize the difference? Also, `FindMaximum` and `NMaximum` find the same value of the maximum for two different pairs of `\[Alpha]` and `\[Chi]`. Which one to use? My point is, which approach should one take?

Comment: @JunaidAftab, if you need a global maximum use `NMaximize`, if a local maximum will do, use `FindMaximum`. There is a tutorial in the documentation about [Numerical Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalOptimization.html)

Comment: Simon, when I use the command `Table[NMaximize[{Re[new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], \[Tau]] - old[\[Tau]]], 
   0 <= \[Alpha] <= 2 \[Pi], 
   0 <= \[Chi] <= \[Pi]}, {\[Alpha], \[Chi]}], {\[Tau], 0.1, 1, 0.1}]` I get the error  `Infinity::indet: "Indeterminate expression (0. +0.\ I) ComplexInfinity encountered"` What seems to be the issue?

Comment: I am able to use `NMaximize` for `\[Tau]` between `0.1` and `0.9`. For values between `1` and `2`, I get this error. I can't chat this thread out; or else I'd show you the errors via a picture.

Comment: When I use `NMaximize[{Chop[new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], 1.0] - old[1.0]], 
  0 <= \[Alpha] <= 2 \[Pi], 0 <= \[Chi] <= \[Pi]}, {\[Alpha], \[Chi]}]`, I get the error: `The function value 0.07491799986821979 -2.2057008373640986*^-18 I is \
not a real number at {\[Alpha],\[Chi]} = \
{6.201806522051993,2.61304274594296`}. >>`

Comment: By eye balling the graphs I have made, I can try and use the `FindMaximum` command -- and it works. But that's not what I want to do. I want to find the global maximum -- hence, I want to use `NMaximize`.

Comment: @JunaidAftab, I added a note at the end